# Mysql: Unable to drop a columns NULL default

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mariadb-10.3

Running mariadb 10.3

I have a bunch of columns that were created by default as NULL defaults. I was asked by a third party integrator to remove the NULL defaults, but so far have been unsuccessful.

I first do:

```
mysql> Describe Tablename;
```

I see my columns with Null defaults. e.g:

```
+--------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------------------+
| Field                    | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra             |
+--------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------------------+
| Tech ID                  | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment    |
| State                    | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | 1       |                   |
| Ref ProdID               | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                   |
| Prenom                   | varchar(50)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                   |
```

Then I do:

```
mysql>ALTER TABLE Tablename ALTER COLUMN Prenom DROP DEFAULT;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.002 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Describe again shows that the Null default has not been removed from column `Prenom`.

```
+--------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------------------+
| Tech ID                  | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment    |
| State                    | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | 1       |                   |
| Ref ProdID               | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                   |
| Prenom                   | varchar(50)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                   |
```

Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: Default null is the lack of a default value. You need to add a default value if you dont want null as default.

Comment: Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.  And it will provide the syntax needed to make the change you require.

Comment: Are you asking about the `NULL / NOT NULL` attribute of a column?  Or about the `DEFAULT` value for a column?  There is an especially confusing case of `NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL` -- maybe just that case is of interest.  (Note that `Ref ProdID` is in that state!)  Does the 'integrator' really know what he wants?

Comment: Thanks @RickJames. I am confirming that this is about DEFAULT NULL, and not about NOT NULL. At the end of the day, it turns out that my ALTER statement were successful, but DESCRIBE did not report correctly.  SHOW CREATE should be used instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN Prenom  DROP DEFAULT
```

Does remove the default as showed in `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and attempting to insert without a value results in an error.

It appears `DESCRIBE TABLE` is using NULL as both a literal, and without a value in its output. Always rely on `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

> ```
> select version();
> ```
>
> ```
> | version()                                   |
> | :------------------------------------------ |
> | 10.3.11-MariaDB-1:10.3.11+maria~stretch-log |
> ```

> ```
> create table TableName ( Prenom  varchar(50) )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> show create table TableName
> ```
>
> ```
> Table     | Create Table                                                                                               
> :-------- | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TableName | CREATE TABLE `TableName` (`Prenom` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN Prenom  DROP DEFAULT
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> show create table TableName
> ```
>
> ```
> Table     | Create Table                                                                                  
> :-------- | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TableName | CREATE TABLE `TableName` (`Prenom` varchar(50)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
> ```

> ```
> insert into TableName VALUES ()
> ```
>
> ```
> Field 'Prenom' doesn't have a default value
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=1275a30c893b3587f9a689a5c0736fa5)*

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. This is good lesson for me, as I kept trying various tools (graphical or CLI) which kept reporting the Null defaults even if I had run the alter command.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your integrator was asking to remove the `NULL` from the column.

First check there are no `NULL` columns:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Prenom IS NULL
```

Or to set to empty string:

```
UPDATE TableName SET Prenom = "" WHERE Prenom IS NULL
```

Then NULL for the column can removed with:

> ```
> select version();
> ```
>
> ```
> | version()                                   |
> | :------------------------------------------ |
> | 10.3.11-MariaDB-1:10.3.11+maria~stretch-log |
> ```

> ```
> create table TableName ( Prenom  varchar(50) )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> show create table TableName
> ```
>
> ```
> Table     | Create Table                                                                                               
> :-------- | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TableName | CREATE TABLE `TableName` (`Prenom` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE TableName MODIFY COLUMN Prenom varchar(50) NOT NULL
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> show create table TableName
> ```
>
> ```
> Table     | Create Table                                                                                           
> :-------- | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TableName | CREATE TABLE `TableName` (`Prenom` varchar(50) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=73b12f38dc9a9466c609ed156e8effdb)*

Comment: Actually this is what I thought too at first. But then they said they wanted me to "Clear the defaults" and suggested the command: ALTER TABLE Tablename ALTER COLUMN Prenom DROP DEFAULT;

Comment: Ah, as per other answer, don't rely on `DESCRIBE TABLE` to verify.

Answer (score 0):

when you execute `ALTER TABLE Tablename ALTER COLUMN COL_NAME DROP DEFAULT;` it will change the default value you specified in the create table script and change it to default one for MySQL which is `NULL`.

[image]

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

So At the end of the day, it turns out that my ALTER statements were successful, but DESCRIBE did not report correctly. As recommended by @danblack, SHOW CREATE should be used instead and will report accurately that the NULL defaults have been dropped.

Answer (score 0):

(Not really an answer - but discussing `DEFAULT`.)

```
mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (
           n INT NULL,
           nn INT NOT NULL,
           ndn INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
           nndn INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0   -- (does not allow DEFAULT NULL)
   );

mysql> DESCRIBE t;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| n     | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| nn    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ndn   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| nndn  | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE t\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: t
Create Table: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `t` (
  `n` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nn` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ndn` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nndn` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci

mysql> ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN ndn DROP DEFAULT,
                     ALTER COLUMN nndn DROP DEFAULT;

mysql> DESCRIBE t;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| n     | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| nn    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ndn   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| nndn  | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE t\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: t
Create Table: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `t` (
  `n` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nn` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ndn` int(11),
  `nndn` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

Interpretation:  In `DESCRIBE`, `DEFAULT NULL` ambiguously means one of two things:

- `DEFAULT NULL`, or
- there is no default.

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` can distinguish the two.

Further experimentation shows what happens when you insert NULLs:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO t VALUES (11,22,33,44);

mysql> INSERT INTO t VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'nn' cannot be null

mysql> INSERT INTO t VALUES (NULL, 77, NULL, NULL);
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'nndn' cannot be null
```

Conclusion:  NOT NULL disallows inserting a NULL.  Let's continue anyway.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO t VALUES (NULL, 77, NULL, 777);

mysql> SELECT * FROM t;
+------+----+------+------+
| n    | nn | ndn  | nndn |
+------+----+------+------+
|   11 | 22 |   33 |   44 |
| NULL | 77 | NULL |  777 |
+------+----+------+------+
```

I'm not through yet!  What if you present *nothing* for a value?  What if there is no `DEFAULT`?

```
mysql> INSERT INTO t () VALUES ();
Query OK, 1 row affected, 3 warnings (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                   |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1364 | Field 'nn' doesn't have a default value   |
| Warning | 1364 | Field 'ndn' doesn't have a default value  |
| Warning | 1364 | Field 'nndn' doesn't have a default value |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What??  I would expect 2 or 4 Warnings, not 3.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM t;
+------+----+------+------+
| n    | nn | ndn  | nndn |
+------+----+------+------+
|   11 | 22 |   33 |   44 |
| NULL | 77 | NULL |  777 |
| NULL |  0 | NULL |    0 |  -- So, as if "DEFAULT 0"
+------+----+------+------+
```

There may be more to this saga.